# Importing a library in MS Visual Studio from the same solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies, solution

So I have my solution file here, which contains 4 projects.

- *Project A* is a library which gets compiled into a *.lib*.
- *Project B* is a program which becomes an *.exe*.

I have set up *Project A* as dependency for *Project B*, and I included

```
#pragma comment(lib,"terrain.lib")
```

into the file in *Project B* which uses the library.

In spite of both projects being compiled into the same *Debug* / *Release* folder, MSVCC tells me

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: File "terrain.lib" could not be opened.
// <freely translated from German, could mean "not found">
```

This:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"../Debug/terrain.lib")
```

works, but then I have to change it for release.

Is the only valid way for this using *#ifdef* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify library path in project settings ("additional library directories" in linker settings - at least in vc2008), for both debug and release configuration. You can use macros like ${ConfigurationName} and ${SolutionDir}, so specifying paths within project should be easy enough.

Also it might be a better idea to include libraries using linker settings instead of `#pragma comment`.

Comment: thanks, setting that works now.
I still find it confusing that I have to add the path to the libraries since it's set as a required project...